# Using AES for file integrity checks, replacing MD5

Tags: encryption, md5, hash, aes

First off: I know that AES is a block cipher and not a hashing function. However, I'm stuck with a micro controller with very little RAM and flash memory, and AES-128 is already implemented on it and used for its intended purpose - encryption.

Unfortunately, I'll also have to implement a hashing function for file integrity checks on the same micro controller. Given the limited resources, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the existing AES algorithm instead of MD5 for hashing. One possibility to do that would be:

1. Encrypt the first block of the file using a dummy key (like all zeroes for example)
2. Encrypt the next block using the previous encrypted block as the key
3. Continue this way until all data in the file has been processed
4. Use the last encrypted block as the hash

In theory, I think this should work. If there is corrupted data anywhere in the file, it would lead to differences in all subsequent blocks.

Now, the big question is: How well would this method perform in terms of collisions? Or to put it differently: How well would the final "hash" be distributed?

Comment: I am wondering if your custom scheme would take less place on device than implementation of some SHA algorithm or at least CRC32.

Comment: Since AES is already on the device, my custom scheme would take almost no extra space. CRC32 is not enough, since the integrity check is used for validating firmware updates to be loaded onto the micro controller. Even a single bit error would render the device completely unusable.

Comment: Remember who your adversary is.  If it's just line noise, then using a check designed to catch line noise is probably fine, since you have no malicious adversary.  You're only guarding against being unlucky, so a one in 2^32 chance of corruption still means you can expect to update the firmware once a second for 68 years and never see a problem.  I strongly suggest at least comparing your AES-128 solution against a plain old CRC32 and seeing whether there's a measurable difference against non-malicious corruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [AES-CMAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/SP_800-38B.pdf), an authentication algorithm based in AES.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You may want to have look at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/aes-hash/aeshash.pdf This describes an AES hashing method. Unfortunately, it's not very detailed.

Comment: @Makai: There is a link in my answer with very detailed information.

Comment: AES-CMAC is indeed a valid option, which not only provides integrity, but also authenticity validation. If I got the principle correctly, the concept is similar to the method I proposed, except for XOR-ing the current block with the previously encrypted block and applying the same cipher to all blocks. In addition, there's the padding mechanism that relies on the computed sub keys. I still wonder though how this method compares to MD5 in terms of integrity checks...

Comment: I've implemented AES-CMAC and it's perfectly suited for my purpose. Still running some tests, but good enough to mark this contribution as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most emphatically *yes* you can make a hash function out of AES.  In fact, a number of the submissions for the NIST SHA3 contest, which will decide the next US-government-approved hash function, do [exactly that](http://crypto.rd.francetelecom.com/ECHO/sha3/AES/).

A traditional hash function is just a [cascaded compression function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle-Damg%C3%A5rd_construction), and it's easy to [construct compression functions from block cyphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Construction_from_block_ciphers).  (Some people have also gone the other way, and pulled the [block cypher out of SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHACAL) to use independantly.)

You can, of course, build a proper hash function out of it, but if all you need is file integrity, and therefore *don't* need it to have preimage resistance, collision resistance, or all those other properties that cryptographic hashes have against malicious adversaries, then you can probably even just put your AES chip in whatever chaining mode it has, feed in the file as the message, and use the last block as the hash.  (Just pick fixed values to use for the key and IV.  [Nothing up my sleeve numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number) that look random but aren't are probably good choices, like the first 128 bits after the decimal point in e and pi.)

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed algorithm does not have second pre-image resistance (which also implies that it does not have collision resistance either), so it is not a cryptographically strong hash.

If I have a message `P0 P1 P2` which hashes to `H`, then I can easily construct a second message `Q0 Q1 Q2 QX` that also hashes to `H` - I choose `Q0 Q1 Q2` arbitrarily, then calculate `QX` by *decrypting* `H` with the appropriate key (the encryption of `Q2`).